# App showing hour glass while displaying view with BackgroundImage

Tags: maui

I have an App which uses a `ScrollView` in a `ContentView` with a custom `View` to display a Background Image in XAML like this:

```xml
<ScrollView HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto">

        <views:BackgroundImageView x:Name="BackgroundImage" VerticalOptions="Start"/>

        <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, Auto, *">

            <!-- Border 1:  Custom Picker Control for Saved Store Name and Save-Button -->
            <Border Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource BorderStyleView}">
                <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*, Auto" Margin="15">
                    <picker:CustomPickerControl Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding SelectedSavedStoreName, Mode=TwoWay}" Placeholder="Saved Store..." BorderColor="{x:StaticResource Gray400}" Padding="0, 0, 25, 0" Margin="5, 0, 0, 0"/>

                    <!--Save Button-->
                    <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="Save" HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="100" FontAutoScalingEnabled="True" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="15, 7, 15, 10"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>

        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</ScrollView>
```

In Code-Behind I use `OnSizeAllocated(...)` to set the `HeightRequest` of the Background Image like this (don't know if this is of interest for this question or not):

```cs
protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
    base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);

    if (BackgroundImage == null)
    {
        return;
    }

#if IOS
    if (height > 0)
    {
        BackgroundImage.HeightRequest = height * 0.7;
    }
#endif
#if ANDROID
    if (height > width)
    {
        BackgroundImage.HeightRequest = height * 0.7;
    }
    else
    {
        BackgroundImage.HeightRequest = height;
    }
#endif
}
```

When I open `BackgroundImageView.xaml` I can see the image underlined and it says **"Invalid Value for property 'Source': radiant_gradient.png"**, but the corresponding *.svg file is available for sure in my `..\Resources\Images\`-Folder:

[image]

The bigger problem though is that when I start the App, I can see an Hour Glass for a very long time and the Background Image does not even show up then:

[image]

The App was made to show a different problem in the App and report a Bug for .NET MAUI for a different behaviour, but can be found here:

https://github.com/MAUIoxo/ScrollViewStretchesBeyondScreen_20042

The question for me is why do I see this hour glass for such a long time and then finally the Image is not even showing on *iOS*? I am asking this because I have a similar effect in the real App but there at least the Background Image is showing up. But, there I can also see the Hour Glass for a very long time.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the sample you provided and met the same problem. And I found that the `OnSizeAllocated` method will sit in an infinite loop when I add a breakpoint at it on the iOS platform. So the problem should be caused by this.

And the infinite loop is caused by calling `BackgroundImage.HeightRequest = height * 0.7` in the `OnSizeAllocated` method. So you can put the code into the `ArrangeOverride` method:

```
protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Rect bounds)
    {

        if (BackgroundImage == null)
        {
            return base.ArrangeOverride(bounds) ;
        }

#if IOS
        if (this.Height > 0)
        {
            BackgroundImage.HeightRequest = this.Height * 0.7;
        }
#endif
#if ANDROID
        if (this.Height > this.Width)
        {
            BackgroundImage.HeightRequest = this.Height * 0.7;
        }
        else
        {
            BackgroundImage.HeightRequest = this.Height;
        }
#endif
        return base.ArrangeOverride(bounds);
    }
```

Comment: Great finding! Thank you very much for your help - this must have been it. Also with that, the Background Image is now showing. Do you think in general, that it is not a good idea to do such things like assign a `HeightRequest` in the `OnSizeAllocated(...)` method?

Comment: No, because you have get the parent's height before you assign the height for the image. And I have ocerride all the method to find in the `ArrangeOverride` is the best choice because it will not cause an infinite loop. But there are some other ways. Such as bind the HeightRequest to the ParentView's Height.@OXO

Comment: Okay, I could do this in constructor `BackgroundImage.SetBinding(Image.HeightRequestProperty, new Binding(nameof(Height), source: this));`. My concern was that it is not possible then for me to set the `HeightRequest` correctly when orientation changes. The image in the real App has a linear gradient (in the image itself) from top to bottom. In Portrait mode it ranges up to a certain UI element. I thought it would be logical to see it up to that same UI element again when in Landscape mode and that's why I did these calculations. Do you see a better method to achieve that?

Comment: You can have a try at first. I can't find a better wat to do that.@OXO